# the wife of the king of the Island or island king's wife?

Tags: adjectives, possessives, adjective-phrases, double-possessives

How can I rewrite this sentence?

> 1- He gave a letter to the wife of the king of the Island.
>
> I can think of:
>
> 2- He gave a letter to the island king's wife.
>
> 3- He gave a letter to the King of the island's wife.

How it should be if we try to write it with the possessive form ('S) ? and what is the difference between these two forms if any ?

ِAlso, what if the king's wife was tall or short ?
what is the different ways to add this as well ?

Thank you

Comment: No.1 is correct. The shorter the better, so _he_ _gave_ _a_ _letter_ _to_ _the_ _wife_ _of_ _the_ _island's_ _king_  is best. Adding **'s** to island corrects no. 2. Using double **'s** is correct but awakward and so better avoided. Sentence 3 is correct but should be avoided as it's confusing. It can also mean this: The letter was given to the king of the wife living in that island.

Comment: Thank you very much Rose, it is very helpful, but can you explain the double meaning in sentence 3, how do you get the idea that the wife is living in the island ?

Comment: Suppose Jack is a man who has two wives, W1 who is from country X but who also lives in a foreign island I, and W2 who lives in the countryside. King K is the king of country X. The king is on a visit to I. While being there, he was given the letter. So, the letter was given to the king of  the Island's wife.

Comment: Thank you again for your brilliant explanation, its so clear for me now.

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is better.

The second is also fine in this case, though it sounds awkward. As written, it could mean "the King who rules the wife-of-the-island." Common sense avoids that here, but it wouldn't always.